# Subdomain directed to main domain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have added a subdomain: support.mysite.com

The support directory is in the root directory. Now, whenever I try to access the subdomain, I I am redirected to the index.php file of the main domain.

For example, I try to access support.mysite.com/index.php and ending up at mysite.com/index.php

I guess it has something to do with the htaccess file for the main domain, which is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.(.)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [L,QSA]
```

There is no htaccess file for the subdomain yet.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Try commenting things out until it stops redirecting you.

Comment: Do you have a real directory called `/support/` under `DocumentRoot` of main domain.

Comment: I have created a subdomain via cPanel. My document root contains (apart from the usual directories and files) the support directory and the public_html directory.

Comment: Do you have any .htaccess in support sub directory?

Comment: No I don't have a htaccess in the support sub directory. Only the above htaccess in the main directory.